# reduceByKey a list of lists in PySpark

Tags: group-by, pyspark, rdd, reduce, key-pair

I am new to pyspark and so far it is a bit difficult to understand the way it works specially when you get use to libraries like pandas. But it is seems the way to go for big data.

For my current ETL job, I have the following elements:

This is my rdd:

```
[
    [
    ('SMSG', 'BKT'), ('SQNR', '00000004'), ('STNQ', '06'), ('TRNN', '000001'), ('SMSG', 'BKS'), ('SQNR', '00000005'), ('STNQ', '24'), ('DAIS', '171231'), ('TRNN', '000001'), ....
    ], 
    [
    ('SMSG', 'BKT'), ('SQNR', '00000024'), ('STNQ', '06'), ('TRNN', '000002'), ('NRID', '  '), ('TREC', '020'), ('TRNN', '000002'), ('NRID', '  '), ('TACN', '001'), ('CARF', '          '), ... 
    ],
    ...
]
```

The row data is a fixed size text file.

what I want to do now is to groupByKey each cell of the list.

final result should be:

```
[
    [
    ('SMSG_1', 'BKT'),('SMSG_2','BKS'),('SQNR_1', '00000004'),('SQNR_2', '00000005'),('STNQ_1','06'),('STNQ_2','24'),('TRNN', '000001'),()('DAIS', '171231'),...
    ],
    [
    ('SMSG', 'BKT'),('SQNR', '00000024'),('STNQ','06'),('TRNN', '000002'),('NRID', '  '), ('TREC', '020'), ('TACN', '001'), ('CARF', '          '),...
    ],
    ...
]
```

Basically the rules are as following:

1- if the keys are same and the values are also same remove duplicates.

2- if the keys are same and the values different, rename columns and add a suffix as "_Number" where Number can be replaced by the iteration number of that key.

My code start as following:

```
def addBKT():
...
def prepareTrans():
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_folder = '/Users/admin/Documents/Training/FR20180101HOT' 
    rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles(input_folder).map(lambda x: x[1].split("BKT"))
    rdd = rdd.flatMap(prepareTrans).map(addBKT).map(lambda x: x.split("\n")).map(hot_to_flat_file_v2)
    print(rdd.take(1))
```

The print give me (as shared before) the following list of lists of tuples. I am taking only 1 sublist but the full rdd has about 2000 sublists of tuples:

```
[
    [
    ('SMSG', 'BKT'), ('SQNR', '00000004'), ('STNQ', '06'), ('TRNN', '000001'), ('SMSG', 'BKS'), ('SQNR', '00000005'), ('STNQ', '24'), ('DAIS', '171231'), ('TRNN', '000001'), ....
    ]
]
```

I tried to reduce first the nested lists as following:

```
rdd = rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).reduceByKey(list)
```

I was expecting as result a new list of lists without duplicates and for the tuples with different values, group them all under the same key. However, I am not able to do that.

As second step, I was planning to transform tuples with multiple values to  new pairs of tuples as much as I got values in the grouped tuple: i.e. ('Key', ['Value1', 'Value2']) become ('Key_1', 'Value1'),('Key_2', 'Value2')

Finally, the output of all these transformations is to convert the final RDD to a DataFrame and store it in parquet format.

I really hope someone did something like that in the past. I took a lot of time to try doing this but I am not able to make it nor I was able to find any example online.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are new to spark, You may not aware of Spark Dataframe. Dataframe is advanced concept compared to RDD. Here I solved your problem using Pyspark Dataframe. Have a look into this, Dont hesitate to learn spark Dataframe.

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([("SMSG", "BKT"), ("SMSG", "BKT"), ("SMSG", "BKS"), ('SQNR', '00000004'), ('SQNR', '00000005') ])
rddToDF = rdd1.toDF(["C1", "C2"])
+----+--------+
|  C1|      C2|
+----+--------+
|SMSG|     BKT|
|SMSG|     BKT|
|SMSG|     BKS|
|SQNR|00000004|
|SQNR|00000005|
+----+--------+

DfRmDup = rddToDF.drop_duplicates() #Removing duplicates from Dataframe
DfRmDup.show()
+----+--------+
|  C1|      C2|
+----+--------+
|SQNR|00000004|
|SMSG|     BKT|
|SQNR|00000005|
|SMSG|     BKS|
+----+--------+

rank = DfRmDup.withColumn("rank", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("C1").orderBy(asc("C2"))))
rank.show()
+----+--------+----+
|  C1|      C2|rank|
+----+--------+----+
|SQNR|00000004|   1|
|SQNR|00000005|   2|
|SMSG|     BKS|   1|
|SMSG|     BKT|   2|
+----+--------+----+

rank.withColumn("C1", concat(col("C1"), lit("_"), col("rank"))).drop("rank").show()
+------+--------+
|    C1|      C2|
+------+--------+
|SQNR_1|00000004|
|SQNR_2|00000005|
|SMSG_1|     BKS|
|SMSG_2|     BKT|
+------+--------+

#Converting back to RDD
rank.withColumn("C1", concat(col("C1"), lit("_"), col("rank"))).drop("rank").rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1])).collect()

[('SQNR_1', '00000004'),
 ('SQNR_2', '00000005'),
 ('SMSG_1', 'BKS'),
 ('SMSG_2', 'BKT')]
```

Comment: Hi Pradeep, thank you very much, it is solving almost my problem, the only part I am missing is that I have a list of lists and each list is one row in my final DataFrame. i.e. : [[("SMSG", "BKT"), ('SQNR', '00000004')],[("SMSG", "BKS"), ('SQNR', '00000006')]] should be as result : +------+--------+
| SMSG| SQNR|
+------+--------+
|BKT |00000004|
|BKS |00000005|
+------+--------+

Comment: Another issue I had when creating the DF, is that some of my values are not str. Is it an issue ? because I had some errors in the past where I think pyspark was expecting a schema in order to create the DF. Should I give toDF a schema with the type of each column? if yes, I don't know all the column in in advance. Each list may have different columns. In pandas it was possible for me as you can add dynamically the columns.

Comment: @MehdiMansouri, Try this way they mentioned in the ans section.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259621/spark-todf-createdataframe-type-inference-doesnt-work-as-expected

Comment: Hi Pradeep, I tried the solution provided in the link. The dataframe get created succesfully, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a lot for the link, I follwed the solution provided. The dataframe got created successfully, which is great.

```
    input_folder = '/Users/admin/Documents/Training/FR20180101HOT' 
    rdd_split = sc.wholeTextFiles(input_folder).map(lambda x: x[1].split("BKT"))
    rdd_trans = rdd_split.flatMap(prepareTrans).map(addBKT).map(lambda x: x.split("\n")).map(hot_to_flat_file_v2)
    #rdd_group = rdd_trans.map(lambda x : x[i] for i in range(len(x))).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: str(x) + ','+ str(y))   
    df = spark.read.options(inferSchema="true").csv(rdd_trans)
    print(df.show(1))
```

The print show me something like that:

```
+--------+-------+--------+------------+--------+------+--------+----------+----...

|     _c0|    _c1|     _c2|         _c3|     _c4|   _c5|     _c6|       _c7|     _c8|   _c9|    _c10|   _c11|    _c12|   _c13|    _c14|          _c15|    _c16|                _c17|    _c18|    _c19|    _c20|              _c21|    _c22| _c23|    _c24| _c25|    _c26| _c27|    _c28| _c29|    _c30|                _c31|    _c32|   _c33|    _c34|        _c35|    _c36|  _c37|    _c38|      _c39|    _c40|      _c41|    _c42|              _c43|    _c44| _c45|    _c46|    _c47|    _c48|   _c49|    _c50|        _c51|    _c52| _c53|    _c54|               _c55|    _c56|    _c57|    _c58|          _c59|    _c60|             _c61|    _c62|    _c63|    _c64|                _c65|    _c66|   _c67|    _c68|        _c69|    _c70|  _c71|    _c72|      _c73|    _c74|      _c75|    _c76|              _c77|    _c78| _c79|    _c80|   _c81|    _c82| _c83|      _c84|        _c85|      _c86|   _c87|      _c88|        _c89|      _c90|   _c91|      _c92|        _c93|      _c94|   _c95|    _c96|    _c97|    _c98|  _c99|   _c100|   _c101|   _c102|  _c103|   _c104|       _c105|   _c106| _c107|   _c108|     _c109|   _c110|     _c111|   _c112|             _c113|   _c114|_c115|   _c116|_c117|   _c118|_c119|     _c120|       _c121|     _c122| _c123|     _c124|       _c125|     _c126| _c127|     _c128|       _c129|     _c130|  _c131|   _c132|_c133|   _c134| _c135|   _c136|   _c137|   _c138|  _c139|   _c140|       _c141|   _c142| _c143|   _c144|     _c145|   _c146|     _c147|   _c148|             _c149|   _c150|_c151|   _c152|_c153|   _c154|_c155|     _c156|       _c157|     _c158| _c159|     _c160|       _c161|     _c162|_c163|     _c164|       _c165|     _c166|  _c167|   _c168|_c169|   _c170| _c171|   _c172|   _c173|   _c174|  _c175|   _c176|       _c177|   _c178| _c179|   _c180|     _c181|   _c182|     _c183|   _c184|             _c185|   _c186|_c187|   _c188|_c189|   _c190|_c191|     _c192|       _c193|     _c194|  _c195|     _c196|       _c197|     _c198| _c199|     _c200|       _c201|     _c202|  _c203|   _c204|_c205|   _c206| _c207|   _c208|   _c209|   _c210|  _c211|   _c212|       _c213|   _c214| _c215|   _c216|     _c217|   _c218|     _c219|   _c220|             _c221|   _c222|_c223|   _c224|_c225|   _c226|_c227|     _c228|       _c229|     _c230| _c231|     _c232|       _c233|     _c234| _c235|     _c236|       _c237|     _c238|  _c239|   _c240|_c241|   _c242| _c243|   _c244|   _c245|   _c246|  _c247|   _c248|       _c249|   _c250| _c251|   _c252|     _c253|   _c254|     _c255|   _c256|             _c257|   _c258|_c259|   _c260|_c261|   _c262|_c263|     _c264|       _c265|     _c266| _c267|     _c268|       _c269|     _c270|_c271|     _c272|       _c273|     _c274|_c275|   _c276|_c277|   _c278| _c279|   _c280|   _c281|   _c282|  _c283|   _c284|       _c285|   _c286| _c287|   _c288|     _c289|   _c290|     _c291|   _c292|             _c293|   _c294|_c295|   _c296|  _c297|   _c298|     _c299|   _c300|    _c301|   _c302|_c303|   _c304|     _c305|   _c306|    _c307|   _c308|_c309|   _c310|    _c311|   _c312|_c313|   _c314|_c315|   _c316|_c317|   _c318|               _c319|   _c320|   _c321|   _c322|  _c323|   _c324|       _c325|   _c326| _c327|   _c328|     _c329|   _c330|     _c331|   _c332|             _c333|   _c334|_c335|   _c336|             _c337|   _c338|  _c339|   _c340|      _c341|   _c342|       _c343|   _c344|               _c345|   _c346|              _c347|   _c348|  _c349|   _c350|       _c351|   _c352| _c353|   _c354|     _c355|   _c356|     _c357|   _c358|             _c359|   _c360|_c361|   _c362|_c363|   _c364|_c365|   _c366|    _c367|   _c368|    _c369|   _c370|    _c371|   _c372|    _c373|   _c374|  _c375|   _c376|_c377|   _c378|    _c379|   _c380| _c381|   _c382|    _c383|   _c384|    _c385|   _c386| _c387|   _c388|  _c389|   _c390|              _c391|   _c392|               _c393|   _c394|  _c395|   _c396|         _c397|   _c398|  _c399|   _c400|       _c401|   _c402| _c403|   _c404|     _c405|   _c406|     _c407|   _c408|             _c409|   _c410|_c411|   _c412|_c413|   _c414|_c415|   _c416|    _c417|   _c418|    _c419|   _c420|    _c421|   _c422|    _c423|   _c424|  _c425|   _c426|_c427|   _c428|    _c429|   _c430| _c431|   _c432|    _c433|   _c434|    _c435|   _c436| _c437|   _c438|  _c439|   _c440|              _c441|   _c442|               _c443|   _c444|  _c445|   _c446|         _c447|   _c448|  _c449|   _c450|       _c451|   _c452| _c453|   _c454|     _c455|   _c456|     _c457|   _c458|             _c459|   _c460|_c461|   _c462|_c463|   _c464|_c465|   _c466|    _c467|   _c468|    _c469|   _c470|    _c471|   _c472|    _c473|   _c474|  _c475|   _c476|_c477|   _c478|    _c479|   _c480| _c481|   _c482|    _c483|   _c484|    _c485|   _c486| _c487|   _c488|  _c489|   _c490|              _c491|   _c492|               _c493|   _c494|  _c495|   _c496|         _c497|   _c498|  _c499|   _c500|       _c501|   _c502| _c503|   _c504|     _c505|   _c506|     _c507|   _c508|             _c509|   _c510|_c511|   _c512|_c513|   _c514|_c515|   _c516|    _c517|   _c518|    _c519|   _c520|    _c521|   _c522|    _c523|   _c524|  _c525|   _c526|_c527|   _c528|    _c529|   _c530| _c531|   _c532|    _c533|   _c534|    _c535|   _c536| _c537|   _c538|  _c539|   _c540|              _c541|   _c542|               _c543|   _c544|  _c545|   _c546|         _c547|   _c548|  _c549|   _c550|       _c551|   _c552| _c553|   _c554|     _c555|   _c556|     _c557|   _c558|             _c559|   _c560|_c561|   _c562|           _c563|   _c564|_c565|   _c566|           _c567|   _c568|           _c569|   _c570|   _c571|   _c572|_c573|   _c574|     _c575|   _c576|_c577|   _c578|_c579|   _c580|       _c581|   _c582|               _c583|   _c584|  _c585|   _c586|       _c587|   _c588| _c589|   _c590|     _c591|   _c592|     _c593|   _c594|             _c595|   _c596|_c597|   _c598|               _c599|   _c600|               _c601|   _c602|      _c603|   _c604|  _c605|   _c606|       _c607|   _c608|  _c609|   _c610|       _c611|   _c612| _c613|   _c614|     _c615|   _c616|     _c617|   _c618|             _c619|   _c620|_c621|   _c622|_c623|   _c624|               _c625|   _c626|               _c627|   _c628|  _c629|   _c630|       _c631|   _c632| _c633|   _c634|     _c635|   _c636|     _c637|   _c638|             _c639|   _c640|_c641|   _c642|_c643|   _c644|               _c645|   _c646|       _c647|   _c648|  _c649|   _c650|       _c651|   _c652| _c653|   _c654|     _c655|   _c656|     _c657|   _c658|             _c659|   _c660|_c661|   _c662|_c663|   _c664|               _c665|   _c666|       _c667|   _c668|  _c669|   _c670|       _c671|   _c672| _c673|   _c674|     _c675|   _c676|     _c677|   _c678|         _c679|   _c680|   _c681|   _c682|               _c683|   _c684|   _c685|   _c686| _c687|   _c688|     _c689|   _c690|             _c691|   _c692|     _c693|   _c694|   _c695|   _c696|_c697|   _c698|               _c699|   _c700|    _c701|
+--------+-------+--------+------------+--------+------+--------+----------+-------...

|[('SMSG'| 'BKT')| ('SQNR'| '00000004')| ('STNQ'| '06')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('NRID'| '  ')| ('TREC'| '020')| ('TACN'| '001')| ('CARF'| '          ')| ('CSTF'| '               ...| ('RPSI'| 'SABR')| ('ESAC'| '              ')| ('DISI'| ' ')| ('NRMI'| ' ')| ('NRCT'| ' ')| ('AREI'| ' ')| ('RESD'| '               ...| ('SMSG'| 'BKS')| ('SQNR'| '00000005')| ('STNQ'| '24')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('CPUI'| 'FFFF')| ('CJCP'| '   ')| ('AGTN'| '20212146')| ('RFIC'| ' ')| ('TOUR'| '               ')| ('TRNC'| 'TKTT')| ('TODC'| 'CDGCDG    ')| ('PNRR'| 'IKQOWZ/AA    ')| ('TIIS'| '0000')| ('RESD'| '               ...| ('SMSG'| 'BKS')| ('SQNR'| '00000006')| ('STNQ'| '30')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('COBL'| 225.0)| ('NTFA'| 0.0)| ('TMFT_1'| 'YR      ')| ('TMFA_1'| 300.0)| ('TMFT_2'| 'FR      ')| ('TMFA_2'| 20.81)| ('TMFT_3'| 'QX      ')| ('TMFA_3'| 27.91)| ('TDAM'| 712.92)| ('RESD'| '  ')| ('CUTP'| 'EUR2')| ('SMSG'| 'BKS')| ('SQNR'| '00000007')| ('STNQ'| '30')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('COBL'| 0.0)| ('NTFA'| 0.0)| ('TMFT_1'| 'IZ      ')| ('TMFA_1'| 4.51)| ('TMFT_2'| 'YC      ')| ('TMFA_2'| 9.22)| ('TMFT_3'| 'XY      ')| ('TMFA_3'| 11.74)| ('TDAM'| 0.0)| ('RESD'| '  ')| ('CUTP'| 'EUR2')| ('SMSG'| 'BKS')| ('SQNR'| '00000008')| ('STNQ'| '30')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('COBL'| 0.0)| ('NTFA'| 0.0)| ('TMFT_1'| 'XA      ')| ('TMFA_1'| 6.64)| ('TMFT_2'| 'AY      ')| ('TMFA_2'| 9.4)| ('TMFT_3'| 'WD      ')| ('TMFA_3'| 29.33)| ('TDAM'| 0.0)| ('RESD'| '  ')| ('CUTP'| 'EUR2')| ('SMSG'| 'BKS')| ('SQNR'| '00000009')| ('STNQ'| '30')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('COBL'| 0.0)| ('NTFA'| 0.0)| ('TMFT_1'| 'EK      ')| ('TMFA_1'| 18.89)| ('TMFT_2'| 'EL      ')| ('TMFA_2'| 4.19)| ('TMFT_3'| 'HG      ')| ('TMFA_3'| 16.76)| ('TDAM'| 0.0)| ('RESD'| '  ')| ('CUTP'| 'EUR2')| ('SMSG'| 'BKS')| ('SQNR'| '00000010')| ('STNQ'| '30')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('COBL'| 0.0)| ('NTFA'| 0.0)| ('TMFT_1'| 'JT      ')| ('TMFA_1'| 2.52)| ('TMFT_2'| 'UC      ')| ('TMFA_2'| 6.72)| ('TMFT_3'| 'QK      ')| ('TMFA_3'| 16.76)| ('TDAM'| 0.0)| ('RESD'| '  ')| ('CUTP'| 'EUR2')| ('SMSG'| 'BKS')| ('SQNR'| '00000011')| ('STNQ'| '30')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('COBL'| 0.0)| ('NTFA'| 0.0)| ('TMFT_1'| 'XF      ')| ('TMFA_1'| 2.52)| ('TMFT_2'| 'XFCLT3  ')| ('TMFA_2'| 0.0)| ('TMFT_3'| '        ')| ('TMFA_3'| 0.0)| ('TDAM'| 0.0)| ('RESD'| '  ')| ('CUTP'| 'EUR2')| ('SMSG'| 'BKS')| ('SQNR'| '00000012')| ('STNQ'| '39')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('STAT'| 'I  ')| ('COTP'| '      ')| ('CORT'| '00000')| ('COAM'| 0.0)| ('SPTP'| '      ')| ('SPRT'| '00000')| ('SPAM'| 0.0)| ('EFRT'| '00000')| ('EFCO'| 0.0)| ('APBC'| 0.0)| ('RDII'| ' ')| ('RESD'| '               ...| ('CUTP'| 'EUR2')| ('SMSG'| 'BKS')| ('SQNR'| '00000013')| ('STNQ'| '46')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('ORIT'| '              ')| ('ORIL'| '   ')| ('ORID'| '       ')| ('ORIA'| '00000000')| ('ENRS'| 'NONREF/RESTRICT...| ('RESD'| '               ')| ('SMSG'| 'BKI')| ('SQNR'| '00000014')| ('STNQ'| '63')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('SEGI'| '1')| ('STPO'| 'X')| ('NBDA'| '22APR')| ('NADA'| '22APR')| ('ORAC'| 'CDG  ')| ('DSTC'| 'MIA  ')| ('CARR'| 'AA ')| ('CABI'| ' ')| ('FTNR'| '  63 ')| ('RBKD'| 'O ')| ('FTDA'| '22APR')| ('FTDT'| '1155 ')| ('FBST'| 'OK')| ('FBAL'| '1PC')| ('FBTD'| 'OLN0DMN3       ')| ('FFRF'| '               ...| ('FCPT'| '   ')| ('RESD'| '          ')| ('SMSG'| 'BKI')| ('SQNR'| '00000015')| ('STNQ'| '63')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('SEGI'| '2')| ('STPO'| 'O')| ('NBDA'| '22APR')| ('NADA'| '22APR')| ('ORAC'| 'MIA  ')| ('DSTC'| 'MBJ  ')| ('CARR'| 'AA ')| ('CABI'| ' ')| ('FTNR'| '1515 ')| ('RBKD'| 'O ')| ('FTDA'| '22APR')| ('FTDT'| '1801 ')| ('FBST'| 'OK')| ('FBAL'| '1PC')| ('FBTD'| 'OLN0DMN3       ')| ('FFRF'| '               ...| ('FCPT'| '   ')| ('RESD'| '          ')| ('SMSG'| 'BKI')| ('SQNR'| '00000016')| ('STNQ'| '63')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('SEGI'| '3')| ('STPO'| 'X')| ('NBDA'| '29APR')| ('NADA'| '29APR')| ('ORAC'| 'MBJ  ')| ('DSTC'| 'CLT  ')| ('CARR'| 'AA ')| ('CABI'| ' ')| ('FTNR'| ' 844 ')| ('RBKD'| 'O ')| ('FTDA'| '29APR')| ('FTDT'| '1059 ')| ('FBST'| 'OK')| ('FBAL'| '1PC')| ('FBTD'| 'OLN0DMN3       ')| ('FFRF'| '               ...| ('FCPT'| '   ')| ('RESD'| '          ')| ('SMSG'| 'BKI')| ('SQNR'| '00000017')| ('STNQ'| '63')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('SEGI'| '4')| ('STPO'| ' ')| ('NBDA'| '29APR')| ('NADA'| '29APR')| ('ORAC'| 'CLT  ')| ('DSTC'| 'CDG  ')| ('CARR'| 'AA ')| ('CABI'| ' ')| ('FTNR'| ' 786 ')| ('RBKD'| 'O ')| ('FTDA'| '29APR')| ('FTDT'| '1630 ')| ('FBST'| 'OK')| ('FBAL'| '1PC')| ('FBTD'| 'OLN0DMN3       ')| ('FFRF'| '               ...| ('FCPT'| '   ')| ('RESD'| '          ')| ('SMSG'| 'BAR')| ('SQNR'| '00000018')| ('STNQ'| '64')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('FARE'| 'EUR   225.00')| ('TKMI'| '/')| ('EQFR'| '            ')| ('TOTL'| 'EUR   712.92')| ('SASI'| '0011')| ('FCMI'| '0')| ('BAID'| '      ')| ('BEOT'| ' ')| ('FCPI'| '0')| ('AENT'| '        ')| ('RESD'| '               ...| ('SMSG'| 'BAR')| ('SQNR'| '00000019')| ('STNQ'| '65')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('PXNM'| '               ...| ('PXDA'| '               ...| ('DOBR'| '02APR68')| ('PXTP'| '   ')| ('RESD'| '        ')| ('SMSG'| 'BAR')| ('SQNR'| '00000020')| ('STNQ'| '66')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('FPSN'| '1')| ('FPIN'| 'AA132193       ...| ('RESD'| '               ...| ('SMSG'| 'BKF')| ('SQNR'| '00000021')| ('STNQ'| '81')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('FRCS'| '1')| ('FRCA'| 'PAR AA X/MIA AA...| ('RESD'| '        ')| ('SMSG'| 'BKF')| ('SQNR'| '00000022')| ('STNQ'| '81')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('TDNR'| '0015131574285 ')| ('CDGT'| '2')| ('FRCS'| '2')| ('FRCA'| '1IZ9.22YC11.74X...| ('RESD'| '        ')| ('SMSG'| 'BKP')| ('SQNR'| '00000023')| ('STNQ'| '84')| ('DAIS'| '171231')| ('TRNN'| '000001')| ('FPTP'| 'CA        ')| ('FPAM'| 712.92)| ('FPAC'| '               ...| ('EXDA'| '    ')| ('EXPC'| '  ')| ('APLC'| '      ')| ('INVN'| '              ')| ('INVD'| '000000')| ('REMT'| 712.92)| ('CVVR'| ' ')| ('RESD'| '               ...| ('CUTP'| 'EUR2')]|
+--------+-------+--------+------------+--------+------+--------+----------+-------...
```

I think I still need to go through each pair of columns, rename the second column with the value of the first row of first column and finally, drop all first columns of every pairs of columns.

Or is it possible to add more options to:

```
df = spark.read.options(inferSchema="true").csv(rdd_trans)
```

to get the exact correct dataframe structure? It will avoid more processing time (my goal is to be faster than in pandas version)

In the mean time, I tried to do:

```
df.write.parquet("/Users/admin/Documents/Training/FR20180101HOT.parquet")
```

But got an error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o447851.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    ...
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8220.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8220.0 (TID 12712, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.

...
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
...
```

I can't put all the error message due to limit of text but it seems related to memory issue.

I did a count for the df:

```
print(df.count())

15723
```

Which is equal to the number of rows in my pandas version (other python code not using pyspark) so it is getting the right number of rows. However, in pandas I am able to extract in parquet without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try regexp_replace for your case.
Check the example case below,

```
df1.withColumn("c0", regexp_replace("_c0", "[()']", "")).withColumn("c1", regexp_replace("_c1", "\)", "")).show()

+----+---+---+---+
| _c0|_c1| c0| c1|
+----+---+---+---+
|('a'| 2)|  a|  2|
|('b'| 4)|  b|  4|
|('c'| 6)|  c|  6|
+----+---+---+---+
```